US green card holder: Do I need a transit visa when my journey includes a flight through a Schengen country?
I am a Turkish citizen and US permanent resident. I'm traveling home for my sister's wedding and I booked my flights with Norse like this:
JFK -> OSLO -> ISTANBUL
ISTANBUL -> OSLO -> JFK
Separate tickets booked together, traveling the same day and I will be in Oslo for 2 hours. Do I need a transit or Schengen visa?

No, it doesn't clarify my situation there unfortunately

Basically you need a regular Schengen visa if you need to collect and re-check luggage or of you need to leave the non-Schengen part of the airport for any reason, because that would mean going through passport control, formally entering the Schengen area.  If you don't need to do that, your green card exempts you from the requirement to get an airport transit visa that otherwise applies to Turkish citizens in Norway.  This information is in the linked question, though it may be difficult to extract it.

@phoog I think if its separate tickets the airline may (has to?) prevent boarding at JFK for lack of Schengen visa even if there's no checked in luggage and the OP is checked in to the next flight. Not entirely sure what "separate tickets booked together" means though.

@littleadv I believe "separate tickets booked together" refers to the typical practice of low-cost airlines of treating multiple-leg journeys as separate even if they are booked together.  Since the separate tickets are on the same airline I think it fairly likely that they would treat the passenger as a transfer passenger if possible (i.e. without checked bags) but it is certainly possible that they wouldn't, and I see now that the critical element of this question that isn't covered in the supposed duplicate is that of the individual airline's policy.  I've voted to reopen.

I emailed vfs global, they told me to contact the airline company. I contacted the airline company they told me to speak with vfs global. it is a shitshow.
